# Why the Definition of $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ limit does not exist is defined that way?

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

I was reading Calculus Volume 1 page 211, and was confused about the situation applying the epsilon-delta definition when the limit does not exist.

According the the book, "The lim does not exist if for every real number $L$, there exists a real number $\epsilon > 0$ so that for all $\delta > 0$, there is an $x$ satisfying $0 < |x - a| < \epsilon$, so that $|f(x) - L| \geq \delta$."

As delta and epsilon represent the margins from the a and L, thus both will be bigger than 0, following the definition, we can make up (what is proving something? for me this is making up some special case to "prove" something) some delta and epsilon combination satisfying the condition to "prove" it.

But where does this definition come from?  I really want to know this, please help me

[image]

[image]

Comment: I suggest you to learn how to negate statements. Hammack's Book of Proof is good place to start. https://www.people.vcu.edu/~rhammack/BookOfProof/

Comment: This is not really a definition – rather, it is the correct negation of the statement $(\exists L\in\mathbb R)(\forall\varepsilon>0)(\exists\delta>0)(\forall x)(0<|x-a|<\delta\implies|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$). Roughly speaking, to negate a statement, you have to invert each quantifier and then negate every sub-expression.

Comment: Thank you very much